# От чего зависит переход цвета

Tags: svg

1. Чтобы определить переход цвета надо от 100% вычесть 1 цвет (цвет заполняет фигуру на  50%) и 2 цвет цвет заполняет фигуру на  50%) если значение больше 0 плавный переход цвета будет если меньше то будет резкий переход цвета
2. В этом примере плавного перехода не будет т.к 100% - 50% - 50% = 0;

```html
<svg width="900" height="200" viewBox="0 0 900 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id='a'>
        <stop offset='50%' stop-color='red'></stop>
        <stop stop-color='yellow' offset='50%'></stop>
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>

 <circle  r='70' cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)"></circle>
</svg>
```

1. тут есть переход хотя от 100% - 30% - 70% = 0

```html
<svg width="900" height="200" viewBox="0 0 900 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id='a'>
        <stop offset='30%' stop-color='red'></stop>
        <stop stop-color='yellow' offset='70%'></stop>
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>

 <circle  r='70' cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: от 0 до 30 желтый, от 30 до 70 интерполированный цвет от желтого к красному, от 70 до 100 красный

Comment: ага, я таки ошибся,  в данном случае ситуация зеркальная

Comment: Добавьте третий цвет, для понимания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stop-opacity` надо указывать, пример работы

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 900 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id='a'>
        <stop stop-color='red' offset='0%' stop-opacity="0.7"></stop>
        <stop stop-color='yellow'offset='100%' stop-opacity="1"></stop>
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>

 <circle  r='70' cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)"></circle>
</svg>
```